# C# locale-aware MaskedTextBox mask for DateTime values

Tags: c#, datetime, maskedtextbox

C# locale-aware MaskedTextBox mask for DateTime values

I'm working through FXCop/Code Analysis's Globalization warnings and would like to know the proper, locale-aware way to set and get DateTime values through a MaskedTextBox.

My form has a MaskedTextBox element with its Culture property set to "en-US", and its Mask property set to "00/00/0000" (the predefined Short date format). maskedTextBox.Text = now.ToString() displays without leading-zeros as "42/42/010_", yet I would like it to be represented as "04/24/2010".

Comment: if you are setting the Text property yourself, that you should set the format of the string as such - now.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy") or something such as that. You can get the actual format style here - http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Initially that was the approach I thought about taking, but "mm/dd/yyyy" might change based on the locale. Would it be acceptable then to place it in the program's resx file with the rest of the strings where it can be localized? Or is there a more correct way that lets the runtime handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a user's aspect, no matter how good your MaskedTextBox supports my culture, it is far more difficult to use compared to a DateTimePicker,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx

Comment: Wow, do I feel stupid... I was so focused on the internationalization part of things that I missed the most obvious solution. Thanks for getting me pointed in the right direction!